# How to see output from PhpStorm quality tools?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm trying to run phpcbf in PhpStorm quality tools.

However when I run it through an inspection, it just executes silently and doesn't seem to be working properly.

[image: executing phpcbf from Alt+Enter]

Is there somewhere I can see the output from this execution? I'm sure I could debug it myself if I could, but without the output I can't do much to debug why it's not doing anything.

Comment: You can see the reported message when you hover the mouse over the highlighted code fragment, or by running Code > Inspect Code.

Comment: @Dmitrii that tells me why the code beautifier needs to be run, it doesn’t tell me why the code beautifier failed to execute

Comment: sorry, this wasn't obvious from your initial question. How does it fail exactly? Generally, you can open Help > Diagnostic Tools > **Debug Log Settings...** and add `#com.jetbrains.php` line. Then reproduce the issue and check the logs: that's idea.log at Help > Show log in .... You can find there what command line command was run by IDE & try to launch it manually in terminal - see if the output differs. But I would rather contact PhpStorm team directly with this via Help | Contact Support.